# Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator (Flutter)

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native, flutter

I want to be able to navigate from Main.dart to Exercises.dart.
When I tap on the List Tile in my App Drawer I get the following error:

*Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.*

[Main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq7wo.png)

[exercises.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDy0l.png)

Entire class
[image: Entire class]

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: ive also imported exercises.dart to main.dart

Comment: This has something to do with where the Navigator is called, could u share the entire class?

Comment: hi ive added the class as I have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are not passing the Scaffold context to a separate widget and using it directly.

Either make a separate Widget for this `ListTile` or wrap it with a `Builder` as follow:

```
Builder(
   builder: (context) => ListTile(
     title: Text('Exercises'),
     onTap: () {
       Navigator.of(context).push(
         MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => Exercises(),
         ),
       );
     },
   ),
 ),
```